# FireFox showing Flash button but can't click on it

Tags: jquery, css, flash, firefox, firefox-3

Got a weird bug with FireFox only. I'm using Uploadify - a great jQuery upload utility to allow multiple uploads to my site. I have a Modal Popup which appears in the middle of the window with blackened out background. My Flash upload button is inside this popup.

In all other browsers this works fine, but in FireFox, sometimes (not always) the button will not be clickable. Right clicking on the button, the context menu appears way over to the left above (pretty much at the left edge of the page and within an inch of top of the page)

These people have all had the same problem [Forum Thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1088329.aspx) but there's no answer there.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: Can you post us a snippet of your code or maybe a link to your project?

Comment: That's weird. I've never heard of anything similar in plain old flash, so my first guess is it's something about the modality. It sounds like, for some reason the flash is displayed in the center, but FF thinks it's really somewhere else. Have you tried tweaking stuff with whatever you're using to make it modal?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, I figured it out!

Turns out using `wmode` within the embedded flash was causing the issue. Initially it was `wmode=transparent`, I tried `wmode=opaque`, still didn't seem to work. Ended up removing it entirely and suddenly it started working.

Only problem now is despite working fine in FF3, it doesn't even show in FF2. Guess people should upgrade their browsers :)